# How can I extract a value from a double nested map in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, nested

I am trying to access a column (called auxdata) in SparkSQL that looks like this:

{"data_type":"2", "additional_data": ""{\"session_id\": \"102s\", \"from_user_id\": kkk0000, \"object_id\": \"aaaa68764\"}""}

I would like to extract the object_id within "additional_data".

In Presto I was able to do this as:

select json_extract_scalar(json_parse(cast(json_parse(auxdata['additional_data']) as varchar)), '$.object_id') as obj_id
from table

Is there any way to do this in SparkSQL?

I tried:

select get_json_object(element_at(auxdata, 'additional_data'), '$.object_id') as obj_id
from table

but it returns null.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the json you have provided is incorrect. I modified it in the below example. You can use nested **`get_json_object`** to parse nested json-

```scala
   val data =
      """
        |{"data_type":"2", "additional_data": "{\"session_id\": \"102s\", \"from_user_id\": \"kkk0000\",\"object_id\": \"aaaa68764\"}"}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.range(1).withColumn("auxdata", lit(data))
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |id |auxdata                                                                                                                                |
      * +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      * |0  |
      * {"data_type":"2", "additional_data": "{\"session_id\": \"102s\", \"from_user_id\": \"kkk0000\",
      * \"object_id\": \"aaaa68764\"}"}
      * |
      * +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = false)
      * |-- auxdata: string (nullable = false)
      */

    df.withColumn("obj_id", get_json_object(get_json_object($"auxdata", "$.additional_data"), "$.object_id"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
      * |id |auxdata                                                                                                                               |obj_id   |
      * +---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
      * |0  |
      * {"data_type":"2", "additional_data": "{\"session_id\": \"102s\", \"from_user_id\": \"kkk0000\",\"object_id\": \"aaaa68764\"}"}
      * |aaaa68764|
      * +---+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
      */
```